# Server seems to halt with lots of connections ... Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a dedicated server running about 120 hp scripts that connect to other servers to process commands. Sometimes I cannot gain access via SSH and FTP and I presume this is something to do with no connections being available.

Do I need to change something in apache to allow more connections or is it not as simple as that?

I am running CentOS with Apache. 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your open files limit for the user the scripts/apache are running as.  Sounds like you are running out of file descriptors.

Comment: Where do I find this option?

Comment: Just found `ulimit -aS` and my open files is set to 1024. That not enough?

Comment: `ulimit` applies to specific processes.  `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` for the system-wide limit.  Keep in mind that every file opened and every connection each take a file descriptor, so if someone connects to you, your server opens one script file, and connects to another server, that's a *minimum* of three descriptors per connection, and you probably use more than that (including other scripts, reading data files, etc).

Comment: Is there any calculation I should do to limit this or should I be OK to set this to some really high number? I guess it will just use more RAM ? p.s Current value is: 1572114 - That normal?